# retrieve row result using prepare statement in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

    //retrieve user's id
}
```

I want to check if the user exist and select his ID. I did the first one, can how to get his ID? loop through the row result? or I need to write another SQL? I'm confused with store_result() and get_result() too.

Comment: "I'm confused with store_result() and get_result() too" --- what if you read documentation then?

Comment: @zerkms I still don't get it after I read.

Comment: so you used functions you don't understand? Why did you use them then? Trying random things never leads to success in programming.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. You can either fetch the results into an array or store them and bind to variables. You should almost always choose the first option.

#### Option 1 - `get_result()`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

if ($row) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

#### Option 2 - `store_result()`

*To use this option you must know the order of columns in your result set, which means you should not use `SELECT *`*

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, col2, col3 FROM user WHERE name=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $col2, $col3); // define your variables
    $stmt->fetch(); // fetch a single row fromt he result and assign to the variables
    echo $id; // After fetching the variables will be populated
}
```

As you can see the first options is much easier and cleaner. The only downside is that you might run into problems when using extremely old PHP versions (PHP < 5.4).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should fetch your result after executing the query to retrieve all records as follow

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
{
    $row = $stmt->fetch_array()
    print_r($row); 
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a single user with a given name PS: but if there are multiple - you don't need that `if`

Comment: Yes but user might not exist

Comment: if there are multiple and you have `while` - it doesn't matter - a loop body will just not run. So you need to remove either `if` or `while` - together they are redundant

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()